# WPF: 'ListView.ItemsSource' property is null during 'Loaded' event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

So basically, I have a list view set up in XAML like so:

```
<ListView Margin="0" Name="OpenItemsListView"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataItemListItemTemplate}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OpenItems, Mode=OneWay}" 
    Loaded="OpenItemsListView_Loaded"/>
```

The event handler `OpenItemsListView_Loaded` looks like this:

```
private void OpenItemsListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(((ListView)sender).ItemsSource);
    view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(DataItem.ItemTypeGroup)));
}
```

My problem: I get a null reference exception on the first line of that method because `sender.ItemsSource` is null, even though I bound it to the window's `OpenItems` property in the XAML list view declaration. I also checked to make certain that that property is NOT currently set to null at the time the event handler is called.

So, my question is, how can I make sure my event gets called AFTER the list view is all set up and attached to its ItemsSource? Is there a different event I need to handle? Or do I need to do something really hacky and ugly, like start a thread that keeps checking the property in the background to wait for it to not be null, then set up the groups, and then exit? Or maybe there's a completely different simple and pretty solution I should be using?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't read through the entire description but i think `Loaded` is about UI loaded not the `ItemSource` loaded, as the ItemSource can be binded to a collection that will be populated asynchronously

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not doing this in XAML?

Comment: I suppose you do have a method that populates the `OpenItems` collection, then is it fair to say that the ItemsSource is initialized when that method finishes execution?

Comment: @XAMlMAX - Well, I don't know that there's a way to do it in XAML. If you know of a way, I'd love to hear it in an answer. Still, even if I DID do that, I would still need a way to make sure the group description was added after the ItemsSource property was bound. Any Ideas?

Comment: Just added an answer which will take all of your code behind away. You will not have to check for items source and it will not affect the underlying collection.

Comment: @Alex - I WOULD do that, but I need this event to be applied in XAML, because this grouping needs to happen for each item's list of sub-items via the `ListView.ItemTemplate` that's used for each item. Each item is expandable with its own list of sub-items, if it has any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All this can go away if you assign the collection through XAML:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding OpenItems}" x:Key="items">
   <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
       <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="yourPropertyHere"/>
   </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
   <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
       <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="propertyHere" />
   </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
   <CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
       propertyNameHere
   </CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

this gives you sorting, grouping and filtering available.
You have to add this tag to the top of your `UserControl` or `Window`:

```
xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
```

Then in your ListView use it like so:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}">
```

Comment: Question: How can I do this inside a `<DataTemplate>` that I'm currently using for each item, sub-item, sub-sub-item, etc... in the list? This works for the top-level items, but for sub items and lower, I need to get it into the DataTemplate I'm using for the expandable list view displaying each item's `SubItems`.

Comment: That's easy! you put collectionViewSource in Resources of yuour dataTemplate and refer that inside of the dataTemplate.

Comment: @XAMIMAX - This... is causing the ListView to be empty, as if there were no items in my ObservableCollection, when it was not empty before :'( and again, I'm out of ideas why. Any ideas?

Comment: @PerrinLarson for each dataTemplate that you use you need to assign it to the new collection of data so say your openItem has colelction of AnotherOpenItems now you need to use a dataTemplate that will use `<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding AnotherOpenItems}" x:Key="AnotherItems">` but if this won't work you can use explicit binding trigger

Comment: @PerrinLarson However we are talking about a different issue here. Your question was about Binding the items in your collection. Make sure your ViewModel notifies UI through INotifyPropertyChnaged interface.

Comment: @XAMIMIX - OK, this is going to take some experimentation. Thanks for the tips. At least I have something to go on now. I'll come back to upvote, choose answer, and/or coment further, etc. once I get somewhere. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PerrinLarson have a look at [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/the-update-source-trigger-property/) article it explains on how to use explicit binding updates.

Comment: @XAMIMIX - Putting CollectionViewSource inside the DataTemplate and referring to it as the ListView's ItemsSource is revealing this problem: `'System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource' is not a valid value for property 'ItemsSource'.`

Comment: OK, so I figured this one out, but the answer is complicated. If anyone else needs it in detail, go ahead and ask a question. In short, the `CollectionViewSource` needs to be in the resources of a component of the template, not of the template itself, and of a component higher in the visual tree than the `ListView`. It then needs to be referenced by the `ListView.ItemsSource` property as @XAMIMIX described in his answer.